# How to echo row from custom statement another than $stmt

Tags: php, mysql

My code :

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users, tbl_products WHERE userID=:uid and creatorID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$scheck = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE serialNumber=:snr");
$scheck->execute(array(":snr"=>$snumber));
```

How to echo row from $scheck?

When I type `$row['artNumber']` it's showing row from $stmt.

I try to do `$scheck['artNumber']` but it does not show anything.

I tried to find answer in google, but I did not find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are already using `fetch` on another statement above, why cant you use it here too?

```
$scheckrow = $scheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you can simply do what you're already doing

```
echo $scheckrow['artNumber'];
```